# How can mock object replace all system functionality being tested?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am fairly new to unit testing. And at the moment I have trouble on trying to unit test a Google oAuth Picasa authentication. It involves major changes to the code if I would like to unit tested it (yeah, I develop unit test after the app works).

I have read that Mock Object is probably the way to go. But if I use Mock, how do I know that the functionality (that is Google oAuth Picasa authentication), is really working?

Or, aside that I develop unit testing after the app finished, did I made other mistakes in understanding Mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unit testing, you test a particular unit (function/method...) in *isolation*, meaning that you don't care if other components that your function uses, work (since there are other unit test cases that cover those).

So to answer your question - it's out of the scope of your unit tests whether an external service like Google oAuth works. You just need to tests that you make a correct call to it, and here's where Mock comes in handy. It remembers the call for you to inspect and make some assertions about it, but it prevents the request for actually going out to the external service / component / library / whatever.

**Edit:** If you find your code is too complex and difficult to test, that *might* be an indication that it should be refactored into smaller more manageable pieces.

Comment: The idea of `it's out of the scope of your unit tests whether an external service like Google oAuth works` <== is surprising for me. Don't we want to test this functionality as well? How come we test how our app behave when it succeed on connecting or failed? Just curious, if we create Mock to our class that try to connect with Google Auth (in this example), isn't that we won't achieve a high number of Code Coverage lines ? * Because we don't really test this class, but merely it's mock

Comment: In unit tests we test units of code (e.g. functions) individually. We only test that the logic of a particular function under test is correct and we do that  by mocking things that are external to it. Then, depending on each test case, we simulate different types of responses (e.g. OK, error,...) and check how the function under test handles different possible outcomes. We create as many different test cases as needed to cover all code execution paths. Also, we don't directly test Google oAuth, because that's outside our system's boundaries, it's Google's job to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: ... and just for the sake of completion (and if this is a source of confusion) - there also exist other types of tests beside unit tests. _End-to-end_ tests, for example, test the application as a whole. They basically simulate real-life usages, for example by capturing the browser and simulating user's interactions with it (mouse clicks, key presses...) and observe what happens from the user's point of view. When running such scenarios, the whole application stack participates (UI, backend, database...). In other words, these are the kind of tests that test "everything" at once.

Comment: I guess I kind of confuse with unit test and end-to-end (integration?) test then. In order to get a high number of code coverage result, we do need to test it end-to-end isn't it?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this link](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/04/11/what-are-unit-testing-integration-testing-and-functional-testing/), it explains the differences between the types of tests better than I can do in a short  comment. ||| Regarding high coverage - that's actually easier to achieve with unit tests, because they are very specialized and each focused on a particular small piece of code. But e2e/integration tests are still needed to test what unit tests can't, and that is how the building blocks of an application interact and work with each other as a whole.

Comment: Yes! Correct. Yesterday, using PyCharm, I simply inspect what lines not executed by my unit tests. Based on that, I create another test that try to cover that lines.. ergo, the code coverage gradually increases. Thanks for the link! Clear lots of things